# Why my view is not rendering DateTime

Tags: model-view-controller

I have following Model Class

```
    public class CandidateViewModel
    {
     public string cName { get; set; }
     public DateTime dob { get; set; }
     public DateTime dod { get; set; }
     }
```

my view which is based on this model class does not render TextBoxes for DateTime type. It does render Labels bot not input types. My view model code seems perfectly ok

When I change DateTime Type to String or int etc. then the input boxes are rendered.

Please note that this Model class is not part of the EDM.

***I found the answer***

I found the answer to my own question. I had a DateTime Template under shared folder. I deleted (not excluded) this folder from the project, and no where datetime was rendering HTML. I went to the actual folder on drive C, and physically deleted the Template folder and every thing started working fine.